# Is possible to define an argument with keyword that takes all succeeding arguments into an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I know what `*` and `**` do when defining a method, but I want to know if I can do this:

`some_method("Hi", params: 1, 2, 3)`

And have a definition like this:

```
def some_method(param, my_hash)
  p param # "Hi"
  p my_hash # { params: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
end
```

The problem itself is a clear syntax for writing a `answer_question` method in a `Student`. You would call like this:
`@student.answer_question question_obj, with: answer_instance, another_answer_instance`

### Update:

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
Question has_many Answer
Student has_many Answer through StudentAnswer
Answer has_many Student through StudentAnswer
```

I save which answers a student chose during a survey in StudentAnswer (I need an extra model to copy the answer text to studentanswer, to keep it saved if the answer text changes over time).

Then, my syntax actually is

```
some_student.answer_question question, with: [answer1, answer2]
```

And I want to make it more clear.

Comment: The most similar is `some_method('Hi', params:  (_ = 1, 2, 3))`, but it looks ugly.

Comment: `@student.answer_question question_obj, with: answer_instance, another_answer_instance` is a syntax error. There's not much you can do against it.

Comment: What about `@student.answer(question).with(answer_1, answer_2)`?

Comment: Well, I just was curious, it was nice for me. I'm interested in your proposal @Stefan but I don't know how to that.

Comment: @PedroAdameVergara `answer` returns an object that responds to `with`. What exactly are you trying to do? Your example code doesn't give much insight.

Comment: Updated question @Stefan

Comment: `some_student.answer_question question, with: [answer1, answer2]` is clear as blue water.

Comment: _"I want to make it more clear"_ – I'm not sure if I understand the use case. Does someone have to enter that line manually many times?

Comment: Thank you @AndreyDeineko. If its already "the best it can" then I won't make any change. Stupid "it always can be done better".

Comment: @PedroAdameVergara n/p :) I think there is no such thing as "best it can", it's rather relative and depends on the particular use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
def some_method(param, my_hash = {})
  p param
  p my_hash
end

some_method('Hi', params: [1, 2, 3])
#=> "Hi"
#=> {:params=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

You can not omit the `[]` and call the method as:

```
some_method("Hi", params: 1, 2, 3)
```

It will cause you a syntax error, because `params: 1` is not a valid Ruby object (it is a syntax sugar, that you can pass a *hash as a last argument* omitting the `{}`).

Comment: I know I can do `params: [1, 2, 3]`. My question is if there is a way to omit the `[]` and keep it working.